# Lightning Web Components: Set scroll position on lightning-datatable based on 'key' field value

Tags: lightning-web-components, dom

We are looking to auto-scroll the user to a specific point in a `lightning-datatable`when a button is clicked.

Assuming we referenced the `key-field` attribute `data-row-key-value` in the dom then in HTML I could:

1. Get the `scrollTop` position of the scrollable div (let's call it `tbl`).
2. Find the appropriate `tr` (let's call it `trgt`).
3. Set `tbl.scrolltop = trgt.offsetTop - tbl.offsetTop`.

Is anything like this possible in LWC without access to the DOM elements through `window`?